# A simple pocket calculator

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, calculator

I was searching the internet for some Python exercises, and I've found a lab assignment from **University of Toronto**. Here's the major of it:

> Question 1.
>   Welcome Message In the if `__name__ == "__main__"` block, write code that displays the following: Welcome to the calculator program. Current value: 0
>
> Question 2.
>   Displaying the Current Value Write a function whose signature is `display_current_value()`, and which displays the current value in the calculator. In the if `__name__ == "__main__"` block, test this function by calling it and observing the output.
>
> Question 3.
>   Addition Write a function whose signature is `add(to_add)`, and which adds `to_add` to the current value in the calculator, and modifies the current value accordingly. In the if `__name__ == "__main__"` block, test the function add by calling it, as well as by calling `display_current_value()`.
>   Hint: when modifying global variables from within functions, remember to declare them as global.
>
> Question 4.
>   Multiplication Write a function whose signature is `mult(to_mult)`, and which multiplies the current value in the calculator by `to_mult`, and modifies the current value accordingly. In the if `__name__ == "__main__"` block, test the function.
>
> Question 5.
>   Division Write a function whose signature is `div(to_div)`, and which divides the current value in the calculator by `to_div`, and modifies the current value accordingly. In the if `__name__ == "__main__"` block, test the function. What values of `to_div` might cause problems? Try them to see what happens.
>
> Question 6.
>   Memory and Recall Pocket calculators usually have a memory and a recall button. The memory button saves the current value and the recall button restores the saved value. Implement this functionality.
>
> Question 7.
>   Undo Implement a function that simulates the Undo button: the function restores the previous value that appeared on the screen before the current one.

Here's my solution:

```
current_value = 0
memory = current_value
memo = [current_value]

def is_divisible(x, y):
    """Return whether x is divisible by y. """
    return x % y == 0


def update_list(lst, value):
    """Updates a list with an item. """
    lst.append(value)


def display_current_value():
    """Prints the current value of the calculator. """
    print('Current value:', current_value)


def add(to_add):
    """Adds a number to the current value of the calcalutor. """
    global current_value

    current_value += to_add

    update_list(memo, current_value)


def mult(to_mult):
    """Multiplies the current value of the calcalutor by a number. """
    global current_value

    current_value *= to_mult

    update_list(memo, current_value)


def div(to_div):
    """Divides the current value of the calcalutor by a number. """
    global current_value

    if is_divisible(current_value, to_div):
        current_value //= to_div
    else:
        current_value /= to_div

    update_list(memo, current_value)


def store():
    """Stores the current value. """
    global memory

    memory = current_value


def recall():
    """Recalls the saved value. """
    return memory


def undo():
    """Restores the previous value. """
    global memo

    if len(memo) >= 2:
        global current_value

        current_value = memo[-2]

        memo.pop(-2)


def main():
    print('Welcome to the calculator program.' )
    display_current_value()

    add(6)
    display_current_value()

    mult(2)
    display_current_value()

    div(3)
    display_current_value()

    for iteration in range(3):
        undo()
        display_current_value()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is it possible to implement `undo` without dealing with other functions such as `add`? Is the code well-documented?

Please point out any bad practice or any bug I've made. Please point out how somethings can be done better. And please note that I'm a beginner and a hobbyist.

Comment: In `is_divisible(),` you want to check that `y != 0`, or catch `ZeroDivisionError` exception.

Comment: You may want to rethink your liberal use of `globals`. You can have the same behaviour, and a more robust code, if you send the value in the global to the function, and assign the result of the function.

Comment: @boardrider Please write those comments as an answer

Comment: @boardrider Thanks! Can you make, as Peilonrazy mentioned, your comments an answer with demonstrating code examples?

Comment: Any reason you're not using classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was asked to rewrite my comments as an answer.

- You want to check that your divisor != 0, or catch ZeroDivisionError exception.
- You may want to rethink your liberal use of globals. You can have the same behaviour, and a more robust code, if you send the value in the global to the function, and assign the result of the function.

Here's the code with the above implemented:

```
$ cat calc.py
def is_divisible(x, y):
    """Return whether x is divisible by y. """
    return x % y == 0


def update_list(lst, value):
    """Updates a list with an item. """
    lst.append(value)
    return lst


def display_current_value(current_value):
    """Prints the current value of the calculator. """
    print('Current value:', current_value)


def add(to_add, current_value, memo):
    """Adds a number to the current value of the calcalutor. """

    print (current_value,"+",to_add)
    current_value += to_add

    memo = update_list(memo, current_value)
    return current_value


def mult(to_mult, current_value, memo):
    """Multiplies the current value of the calcalutor by a number. """

    print (current_value,"*",to_mult)
    current_value *= to_mult

    memo = update_list(memo, current_value)
    return current_value


def div(to_div, current_value, memo):
    """Divides the current value of the calcalutor by a number. """

    print (current_value,"/",to_div)
    if to_div != 0:
        if is_divisible(current_value, to_div):
            current_value //= to_div
        else:
            current_value /= to_div
    else:
        print ("you tried division by 0")


    memo = update_list(memo, current_value)
    return current_value


def undo(current_value, memo):
    """Restores the previous value. """

    print("undo")
    if len(memo) >= 2:

        memo.pop()
        current_value = memo[-1]

    return current_value, memo


def main(current_value, memory, memo):
    print('Welcome to the calculator program.' )
    display_current_value(current_value)

    current_value = add(6, current_value, memo)
    display_current_value(current_value)

    current_value = mult(2, current_value, memo)
    display_current_value(current_value)

    current_value = div(3, current_value, memo)
    display_current_value(current_value)

    for iteration in range(3):
        # print("memo",memo)
        current_value, memo = undo(current_value, memo)
        display_current_value(current_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_value = 0
    memory = current_value
    memo = [current_value]
    main(current_value, memory, memo)

$ python3 calc.py
Welcome to the calculator program.
Current value: 0
0 + 6
Current value: 6
6 * 2
Current value: 12
12 / 3
Current value: 4
undo
Current value: 12
undo
Current value: 6
undo
Current value: 0
```

**Note:** for completion sake, you may want to add a function for substruction.

Comment: Thank you, again! That's much better. There's a typo, **'obove'** must be **'above'**. What  about raising a `ZeroDivisionError` in `div` instead of printing? What about putting `print(current_value, '/', to_div)` in the branch of `if to_div != 0:` so if `to_div` is a zero, the mathematically  wrong operation wouldn't be printed?

Comment: Erratum fixed. Thanks. I used print instead of raising an exception, as (1) it's in line with your other coding style, and (2) it would allow the user to enter another (non 0) number - instead of the code exiting ungracefully. However, you're more than encouraged to implement the same within a try-except block, which is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

With your three globals, it's not clear what `memo` is from looking at it. Try `previous_values` instead. Additionally, populating the list with `memory` at the beginning makes me think they're related, which I'm not sure is actually the case.

boardrider suggests passing your globals as arguments to functions. I agree that this would be a good idea. Another approach would to just wrap it all in a `Calculator` class. Classes are good for managing state.

Your undo function is a bit weird:

```
def undo():
    """Restores the previous value. """
    global memo

    if len(memo) >= 2:
        global current_value

        current_value = memo[-2]

        memo.pop(-2)
```

The previous current_value remains in memory, which makes me not trust it. What happens if you repeatedly undo, then operate? I haven't stepped through to verify, but I suspect a bug.

I'd try this instead:

```
def undo():
    if len(memo) >= 2:
        global current_value
        memo.pop()
        current_value = memo[-1]
```

This would maintain the invariant that the current value is always the last item in the list.

My final comment I am much less unsure of, and is probably down to a matter of personal taste:

I'm not sure about this part of your division:

```
if is_divisible(current_value, to_div):
    current_value //= to_div
else:
    current_value /= to_div
```

Is this just to help prevent floating-point rounding errors? I think this is overcomplicating things without fully addressing the problem. What I mean is that I could contrive to multiply together two floating-point numbers that have the same value of integers, and it would yield another floating-point int-like number, which is what it looks like you're trying to avoid here. I just don't see value in worrying about this in one specific case.

As another idea, you could do something like `if current_value == int(current_value): current_value = int(current_value)` after each op.

Comment: Thank you! I've written `is_divisible` to get rid of the unnecessary fraction part where the result must be an integer. For example Python will return `2.0` as the value of `8 / 4`. It's just about the output.